# Tag Wiki Edits on Ask Ubuntu Mobile

Tags: feature-request, tags, editing, tag-wiki

Ask Ubuntu mobile does not let you make tag edits, you have to switch to the full site, make the edits, and switch back. And the editor is temperamental on my mobile browser, sometimes working and sometimes not. So, could the Ask Ubuntu Mobile developers add support for tag wiki edits? Thanks!

Comment: Also, any progress toward this? Thanks!